# defining the init line in a constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, initialization

As a part of writing my first mini-project in object-orinted in c++, I defined two classes as shown below:

```
class Point
{
public:
    Point(int x, int y);
    int getX() const;
    int getY() const;
    void setX(int x);
    void setY(int y);
    void print() const;
private:
    int x, y;
};

class Circle
{
public:
    Circle(int x, int y, int r, int color);
    int getColor() const;
    void setColor(int color);
    bool contains(const Point &p) const;
    void print() const;
private:
    const Point center;
    int radius, color;
};
```

Now, I am trying to define the constructor of the class Circle in that way:

```
Circle::Circle(int x=0,int y=0,int r=0,int color=0)
    :center.x(x)center.y(y),radius(r),color(color)
{  

}
```

but it seems to be wrong, and I dont understand why and why it should be fixed.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you tell us why you think that *"it seems to be wrong"*. Even though this is quite obvious to some readers, you should learn to always include all relevant information when you ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

The data member `center` has the type `Point`. So to initialize it you have to call an appropriate constructor of the class `Point`.

For example

```
Circle::Circle(int x=0,int y=0,int r=0,int color=0):center(x, y),radius(r),color(color)
{  

}
```

Also it makes sense to declare one more constructor for the class Circle like

```
Circle( const Point &center, int r, int color);
```

Comment: @grek40 Comments deleted